# Spark Mllib Random Forest Model FeatureImportance is coming NULL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have a Random forest model for which I am trying to get the featureImportance vector.

```
Map<Object, Object> categoricalFeaturesParam = new HashMap<>();
scala.collection.immutable.Map<Object, Object> categoricalFeatures = (scala.collection.immutable.Map<Object, Object>)
        scala.collection.immutable.Map$.MODULE$.apply(JavaConversions.mapAsScalaMap(categoricalFeaturesParam).toSeq());
int numberOfClasses = 2;
RandomForestClassifier rfc = new RandomForestClassifier();
RandomForestClassificationModel rfm = RandomForestClassificationModel.fromOld(model, rfc, categoricalFeatures, numberOfClasses);
System.out.println(rfm.featureImportances());
```

When I run above code I found featureImportance as null.  Do I need to set anything in specific to get the feature importance for the random forest model.

Tried using 1.6 version of Spark that takes numberOfFeatures fifth argument in  the API but still getting featureImportance as null.

RandomForestClassifier rfc = getRandomForestClassifier( numTrees,  maxBinSize,  maxTreeDepth,  seed,  impurity);
RandomForestClassificationModel rfm = RandomForestClassificationModel.fromOld(model, rfc, categoricalFeatures, numberOfClasses,numberOfFeatures);
System.out.println(rfm.featureImportances());

Stack Trace:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
                at org.apache.spark.ml.tree.impl.RandomForest$.computeFeatureImportance(RandomForest.scala:1152)
                at org.apache.spark.ml.tree.impl.RandomForest$$anonfun$featureImportances$1.apply(RandomForest.scala:1111)
                at org.apache.spark.ml.tree.impl.RandomForest$$anonfun$featureImportances$1.apply(RandomForest.scala:1108)
                at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
                at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
                at org.apache.spark.ml.tree.impl.RandomForest$.featureImportances(RandomForest.scala:1108)
                at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassificationModel.featureImportances$lzycompute(RandomForestClassifier.scala:237)
                at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassificationModel.featureImportances(RandomForestClassifier.scala:237)
                at com.markmonitor.antifraud.ce.ml.CheckFeatureImportance.main(CheckFeatureImportance.java:49)

Comment: interested if an answer appears!

Comment: What version of spark are you using ?

Comment: I don't think you should be using `fromOld`, it's a private method in Scala accessible in Java only due to certain Java/Scala issues. It's even written in the documentation. This might be the source of the issue.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response.  I am using 1.5.0 version of Spark.  The API documentation has defined the fromOld API static RandomForestClassificationModel  fromOld(RandomForestModel oldModel, RandomForestClassifier parent, scala.collection.immutable.Map<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object> categoricalFeatures, int numClasses)
(private[ml]) Convert a model from the old API.  Reference:  https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/classification/RandomForestClassificationModel.html

Comment: My goal is to take the existing model and calculate the feature importance, to see how well the model features did.  The featureImportance API is available at RandomForestClassificationModel level.  fromOld seems to be the only API that takes the model as input.  I feel may be I need to pass some parameter that I am missing.  I also tried setting seed etc. RandomForestClassifier rfc = new RandomForestClassifier(); rfc.setNumTrees(numTrees); rfc.setMaxBins(maxBinSize); rfc.setImpurity(impurity); rfc.setMaxDepth(maxTreeDepth); rfc.setFeatureSubsetStrategy("auto");rfc.setSeed(seed);